# смена текстуры скриптом

Tags: c#, unity3d

мне надо изменение текстуры скриптом, я сделал то как в теории оно должно работать

но оно не работает...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class anim : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public float waits;
    public Texture txt1;
    public Texture txt2;
    public Texture txt3;
    public Material mr;
    public Renderer rend;
    public int Way;
    void Start()
    {
        mr = rend.material;
    }
    
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    waits -= Time.deltaTime;
    mr.mainTexture = txt3;
    if(Way == 0)
    {
        mr.mainTexture = txt1;
    }
    if (Way == 1)
    {
        mr.mainTexture = txt3;
    }
    if (Way == 2)
    {
        mr.mainTexture = txt2;
    }
    if (Way == 3)
    {
        mr.mainTexture = txt3;
        
    }
    if (Way == 4)
    {
        Way = 0;
    }
    if (waits <= -1)
    {
        waits = 0;
        Way += 1;
    }
   // mr.mainTexture = txt1;
}
```

}

изменение при помощи анимации не подойдёт

***все текстуры и рендеры указаны в инспекторе***

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен но возможно нужно проинициализировать поля:

```
public float waits = 0.0f;
...
public int Way = 0;
```

Но лучше изменить код до такого вида, чтобы он более соответствовал стандартам C#:

```
public class Animation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Render")]
    [SerializeField] private Material Material;
    [SerializeField] private Renderer Renderer;
    [SerializeField] private List<Texture> Textures;

    public delegate void Action();

    [SerializeField] private float WaitTime = 1.0f;

    private int CurrentTextureIndex = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        CurrentMaterial = Renderer.material;
        StartCoroutine(Wait(WaitTime, NextTexture));
    }

    public void NextTexture()
    {
        if (CurrentTextureIndex < Textures.Count - 1) {
            CurrentTextureIndex++;
            Material.mainTexture = Textures[CurrentTextureIndex];
        }
        else {
            CurrentTextureIndex = 0;
            Material.mainTexture = Textures[0];
        }
    }
    public void PreviousTexture()
    {
        if (CurrentTextureIndex > 0) {
            CurrentTextureIndex--;
            Material.mainTexture = Textures[CurrentTextureIndex];
        }
        else {
            CurrentTextureIndex = Textures.Count - 1;
            Material.mainTexture = Textures[^1];
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Wait(int WaitTime, Action OnEnd)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitTime);
        OnEnd?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Я тут также переписал код в лучшую сторону
Вот список изменений который я внес:

- Удалил стандартные комментарии
- Добавил модификатор доступа к методу Start
- Изменил модификаторы доступа у полей и сделал их SerializeField для доступа из инспектора
- Заменил поля для каждой текстуры на список
- Удалил метод Update и вместо этого написал корутину для ожидания
- Добавил делегат для вызова в корутине
- Написал два метода для переключения следующей и предыдущей картинки
- Изменил имена полей чтобы они больше соответствовали стандартам C#

Небольшие несоответствия со стандартами могут быть (аргументы функций и переменные должны быть названны в camelCase а не в PascalCase но я предпочииаю в PascalCase а вам мне кажется все равно, но возможно у вас есть свои стандарты для именования объектов) если ошибки не исправяттся можете тогда предоставить вывод в консоль, картинки и другую информацию
В любом случае если проблема не решилась произведенные изменения однозначно улучшили код

Comment: новый код выглядит лучше, но проблема была не в нём. а объекте была анимация, в которой была указана текстура, поэтому оно и не работало